# Match a template pattern only if another pattern is matched

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I have a template function defined only for some types:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod_v<T>, bool> = true >
void serialize(const T & t) { /*serialize POD*/ }

template<>
void serialize(const std::string  & t) { /*serialize string*/ }

//....
```

And I would like to add a std::vector specialization that matches only if T can be serialized

```
template<typename T /*, is_serializable<T> */>
void serialize(const std::vector<T> & t) { /*do something*/ }
```

How can I make this one matching only if T himself matches a serialize() method?

Comment: Can you use C++20 constraint?

Comment: In my specific case yes, but any answer for various c++ standards is good for knowledge

Comment: Do note that `std::is_pod` has been deprecated and may be removed in a future standard.

Comment: That's not a specialization, that's an overload. Can't partially specialize a function template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With C++20 constraints, you might do something like:

```
template <typename T>
void serialize(const std::vector<T>& v)
requires requires (T inner) {serialize(inner);}
{
  // serialize vector
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wzcv8hYvW)

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE variant can be as simple as:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(serialize(std::declval<T>())) >
void serialize(std::vector<T> const& t)
{ /*do something*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pre-C++20 solution: Test if you can serialize a type:

```
template <typename T>
auto is_serializable(T) -> decltype(serialize(std::declval<T>()), std::true_type());
std::false_type is_serializable(...);
template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_serializable_t
    = decltype(is_serializable(std::declval<T>()))::value;
```

With this you can apply the same pattern as you had for the POD types already:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_serializable_t<T>, bool> = true >
void serialize(std::vector<T> const& t)
{ /*do something*/ }
```

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TE1d6sKb7).

**Edit according to comments:**

Actually it does not appear meaningful to serialise a `std::vector` without serialising all of its elements contained. So the most simple solution (KISS principle...) is: Just *doing* the serialisation witout adding any tests at all!!!

```
template<typename T>
void serialize(std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    // you'd most likely need:
    serialize(v.size());
    // but other variants are be possible, too, like e.g. COBS encoding the data,
    // then last element to be added, when deserializing again, would be followed
    // by the sole 0 (or whatever other sentinel) character encountered...

    for(auto& t : v)
    {
        serialize(t);
    }
}
```

The vector would start to serialise its elements, and these then, if yet other vectors, would just do the same – until reaching the base case where T isn't a vector any more. And now the final decision is made: Does an overload exist handling this final T or not, accordingly the code compiles or not ;)

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ybbqoxc9r).

Comment: Thanks! A side question. If I want to serialize a vector of vectors, this doesn't work as the `serialize(const std::vector<T>&)` overload is declared after is_serializable. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @galinette Hm... Actually way too complex! Serialising an entire vector wouldn't make much sense if we didn't serialise all the elements contained within, would it? So we can simply *do* so – and get the final desired result according to the amendment to the question...